# UIWebview failed to load page when website url start with www

Tags: ios, http, web, uiwebview

UIWebview failed to load page when website url start with www
If i'm using http://www then its working.

www.google.com => not working (Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100)
http://www.google.com => working

I just want to know the reason. 
Is there any fix without appending http by manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code snippet to fix it:

```
var url = NSURL(String:"your-website-address")
if url != nil {
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler.{(data, response, error) ->void in 
if error != nil {
//Handle error
} else {
//what you would like to do
}}
```

Comment: we can handle error using web view delegate. but i want to know is there any predefined option to fix this issue without appending http protocol by manually.

Answer (score 0):

`www.google.com` isn't a valid URL; a valid URL includes the scheme. I'm afraid you'll have to add it manually.